# ConcurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair in Xamarin iOS and Android fails

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, task-parallel-library, portable-class-library

Does anyone know if there is anything special to using ConcurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair in a Xamarin iOS or Android project?

Currently I have:

```
private readonly ConcurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair _taskSchedulerPair= new ConcurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair();


public async Task InitializeAsync()
{
    await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        //This code never runs on iOS or Android :-(
        //Do work here
    },
        CancellationToken.None,
        TaskCreationOptions.None,
        _taskSchedulerPair.ExclusiveScheduler);
}
```

Which all works great on Windows boxes, but the new Task being started with the ExclusiveScheduler never runs on iOS or Android.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's [not implemented yet](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/effa4c07ba850bedbe1ff54b2a5df281c058ebcb/mcs/class/corlib/System.Threading.Tasks/ConcurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair.cs).

I confirm that it does not work (all tasks are simply never run); this unit test will fail:

```
[Test]
public void ExclusiveScheduler()
{
    var taskSchedulerPair = new ConcurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair (TaskScheduler.Default);
    var mre = new ManualResetEvent (true);
    var task = Task.Factory.StartNew (() => mre.Set (), CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, taskSchedulerPair.ExclusiveScheduler);
    var result = mre.WaitOne (1000);
    Assert.IsTrue (result);
    Assert.AreEqual (TaskStatus.RanToCompletion, task.Status);
}
```

Comment: I'm confused. It looks like the link you provided shows that the class is implemented. Can you help clarify which part is not implemented?

Comment: The `InternalTaskProcesser` (sic) method that throws `NotImplementedException`. :)  The plumbing is all there to queue work to the thread pool, but the method it queues never actually executes the delegate.

Comment: Now that you point that out I see what I thought was code was actually commented out code. Good eye. Thanks. Definitely not implemented. Would be nice if that exception was bubbled up instead of just letting everything act as if it's just taking a long time to run the tasks.